# Is iconv_set_encoding really deprecated since PHP 5.6?

Tags: php, php-5.6

The [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.iconv-set-encoding.php) says it is not, though I get the following error with PHP 5.6:

```
Deprecated functionality: iconv_set_encoding(): Use of iconv.internal_encoding is deprecated in...
```

It is also not found by the [PHPCompatibility](https://github.com/wimg/PHPCompatibility) Code Sniffer standard. I am a little bit confused about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PHP manual says that on the ["iconv runtime configuration" page](http://php.net/manual/en/iconv.configuration.php):

> iconv.input_encoding string
>
> **Warning**:
>   This feature has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.6.0. Relying on this feature is highly discouraged.

Comment: Thanks, so I guess this manual page is not correct?
http://php.net/manual/en/function.iconv-set-encoding.php
It's a little bit confusing.